# Are there any other ways to share / run code?

Tags: python, ide, share

So I just created a simple script with selenium that automates the login for my University's portal. The first reaction I got from a friend was: ah nice, you can put that on my pc as well. That would be rather hard as he'd have to install python and run it through an IDE or through his terminal or something like that and the user friendliness wouldn't be optimal.

Is there a way that I could like wrap it in a nicer user interface, maybe create an app or something so that I could just share that program? All they'd have to do is then fill in their login details once and the program then logs them in every time they want. I have no clue what the possibilities for that are, therefore I'm asking this question.

And more in general, how do I get to use my python code outside of my IDE? Thusfar, I've created some small projects and ran them in PyCharm and that's it. Once again, I have no clue what the possibilities are so I also don't really know what I'm asking. If anyone gets what I mean by using my code further than only in my IDE, I'd love to hear your suggestions!

Comment: You are looking for [`PyInstaller`](https://www.pyinstaller.org/), which will allow you to create executable files.

Comment: Making the nice interface is mostly on you. For sharing, you can just use py2exe and py2app. Put it into a zip. You can attach it to an email. If that doesn't work, you can always upload it to a web server and share a link.

Comment: Note that dependin on how you use Selenium, you'd also need to ensure your friend's installed browser is supported by the driver you choose

Comment: @KTibow What are the possibilities to make an interface? I don't know whether that should be done in Python with a certain package or whether I should use a different program.

Comment: @Jem Python can work for this. Personally, I find Tkinter and Pygame hard to use, but it's simpler to use one of them instead of an external interface. Tkinter supports tabs and stuff, so it's probably the best option here. You'll need a way to store the password and stuff though.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE running you program is the same as you running your program in the console. But if you dont want them to have python installed (and they have windows) you can maybe convert them to exe with py2exe. But if they have linux, they probably have python installed and can run you program with "python script.py". But tell your friends to install python, if they program or not, it will always come in handy